# ¿Cómo configurar márgenes de impresión?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, impresión, edge

Qué tal comunidad, quisiera saber si alguien podría orientarme para configurar el formato de impresión, lo que pasa es que al imprimir con márgenes solo quiero que se imprima el número de hoja y la **fecha** quitando la **url** de la página y el **título**.

Comment: Si pudieras compartir tu código trabajado hasta ahora sería ideal para darte ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Podés establecer estilos específicos para la versión impresa de una página utilizando los siguientes atributos en las hojas de estilo o media queries.

```css
@media print {
    /* Aquí irían tus reglas CSS específicas para imprimir */
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css" media="print">
       /* Aquí irían tus reglas CSS específicas para imprimir */
</style>
```

Podes modificar los margenes de impresión con los atributos margin y padding de BODY y HTML.

Tambíen puedes revisar esta respuesta donde muestran un truco para ocultar el título, fecha y otros elementos default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573612/9458300